# Detecting temporal changes using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.1, time, change-detection

I want to show urban sprawl in a city over ten year period. I took a MOOC on geospatial revolution, therein a link was shared to do such analysis. I just want to show the urban sprawl, nothing complicated. However, I can't seem to remember that link or technique.

What is the quickest technique to show this type of spatio-temporal changes?

I have no knowledge of the programming. However, I do remember the technique involved the vegetation, and consequently the built-up space over it over some period of time.